# Smooth sections of finite dimensional bundle and covering space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $G$ be a discrete finitely generated group which acts properly and freely on a smooth manifold $M$ with compact quotient $M/G$. Is it right to consider any function $f \in C^{\infty}_c(M)$ (with compact support) as smooth section of some finite vector bundle $f' \in C^{\infty}(M/G, E)$ and then as smooth section of corresponding $G$-equivariant bundle $ C^{\infty}_c(M, \hat{E})$?

If it is correct can I define a Fredholm differential operator $D : C^{\infty}_c(M) \rightarrow C^{\infty}_c(M)$ as $G$-invariant operator on $C^{\infty}_c(M, \hat{E})$?

Comment: I am curious to hear how you see a function on $\mathbb{R}$ as a section of a vector bundle on $\mathbb{S}^1$...

Comment: Equivariant functions valued in a $G$-module are precisely those which descend to sections of a vector bundle. Arbitrary functions clearly don't.

Comment: I consider functions with compact support, which can be described as functions valued in group ring as follows: $f \rightarrow \sum\limits_{g \in G} f(gx)g$ with property $f(gx) = g^{-1}f(x)$

Comment: @abx: The OP takes the functions to have compact support.